# Get content of a dynamic column

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here's my problem, I want to modify a database from a "modify" button, which is on the column of the content to be modified.

```
<tr class ="xyz" id="5">
<td> sd</td>
<td> none</td>
</tr>
```

This is the fifth column of my table.
I'd like to get the text contained in each `<td>` and send them to a js function, is there a way to do it ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Having this HTML structure :

```
<tr class ="xyz" id="5">
    <td> sd</td>
    <td> none</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the way to do it.

```
let tds = Array.from(document.getElementById('5').cells).map(function(elt)   {
    return elt.innerHTML;
}) // tds will now contains [' sd', 'none'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select all tds inside the row with the id "5" via querySelectorAll and then loop through them.

```js
let tds = document.querySelectorAll('[id="5"] td');

for (let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  console.log(tds[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<tr class ="xyz" id="5">
<td> sd</td>
<td> none</td>
</tr>
```

If you use an id or class name that starts with a digit, you can't use the "#" and "." selectors.

Comment: I was unclear, the html I gave you was the generated one from the js code. id correspond to the index of my row while its generated from a foreach on php, so I don't know which id it is when the button is clicked (one button is generated per row) and that's what I need to know

Comment: Where is the button exactly? Inside a <td> of your row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM to achieve this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id="5">
        <td>Row1 cell1</td>
        <td>Row1 cell2</td>
    </tr>
```

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.namedItem("5").cells;    
console.log(x[0].innerHTML);
console.log(x[1].innerHTML);
```

output：
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtflY.png)

Then you can change the content of the cell by :

```
x[0].innerHTML = "new content";
x[1].innerHTML = "new content";
```